# How to create Single Logic App with multiple HTTP Request Invoker

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I want multiple Http invoker(Http Trigger) in logic app. Logic app is not allowing another invoker(Http Trigger) in app.

[Logic app with single invoker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDriW.png)

I want multiple HTTP request invoke(In EX. - When Http request is received(Trigger)) in single logic app.

Please let me know any workaround.

Comment: Could you please describe your use case ? it will be easier for us to provide you some feedbacks/advices if you can detail what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't have multiple Triggers in a single Logic App, you can separate the Triggers from the working logic.

Basically, create 1 Logic App with each Trigger format, then have all your Trigger Logic Apps call the same working Logic App.